# Maya Resizing Handles Too Big

Tags: maya

The handles we use for resizing or moving or rotating are too large and they exceed the screen.

[image]

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/urdh2v3v7/     here is screenshot

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: its been solved i dont know how to close this question now

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting the minus/hyphen(-) key a few times on your keyboard. Hitting the plus(+) makes the gizmo bigger if you might have guessed.